# Firebase initialized but it doesn't generating token (Xamarin.Android)

Tags: android, firebase, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am using nuget packages like, **Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging version : 57.1104.0-beta1** and **Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base version : 57.1104.0-beta1**, i have also added a required firebase service "FirebaseInstanceIdService" class for firebase implementation(For Notification) in my Android project in Xamarin.Forms application. Here thing is, i am facing an issue regarding firebase token. It seems null, even if i find FirebaseApp initialized as shown in below image link: [redirect to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5iUzv.png)

I have moved on to this version of nuget package(57.1104.0-beta1) from the version (42.1021.1) by referring [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44164905/7237468).
Because I was facing same exception as described in this answer, While I am going to initialize **FirebaseApp** in **MainActivity.cs** in my Android Project.

Comment: Whether this document you refer to (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/data-cloud/google-messaging/remote-notifications-with-fcm?tabs=windows)?

Comment: Can you check if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48089829/7462031) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48922248/7462031) helps you

Comment: To add more to this why are you using beta packages it is always advised you use latest stable version and if I am not wrong there are latest stable versions which are higher than this.

Comment: I had tried latest stable *Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging -Version 60.1142.1* and *Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement -Version 60.1142.1* from *-Version 42.1021.1* and than i referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44164905/7237468), so i followed the post. But still its not working everytime.